# How to add a tilde "~" in between two letters (\alpha and l)? I attached my text below:

Tags: symbols, characters, tilde

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 
    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\! \, \cdot \! \,}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
    %Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

$\alpha ~ l$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Not exactly a *minimal* example, isn't it? Next time try to trim it down:  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` is an unbreakable space in LaTeX. You can find special characters to LaTeX here: https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-03

You can find a symbol following [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara) — in this case you can find

[image]

and given that you want it in math mode, the simplest solution is

```
$\alpha\sim I$
```